# Wrote a script to get the http response. But script breaks if there is a url that doesnot exist

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Below is the code to get the http response:

```
import requests
import xlrd
import xlwt

file_location = "C:/Users/Nitin Kansal/Desktop/rc/Cashkaro.xlsx"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

urls = []
for r in range(sheet.nrows):
    urls.append(sheet.cell_value(r,0))

book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding = "utf-8", style_compression = 0)
sheet = book.add_sheet("Sheet1", cell_overwrite_ok = True)

for index, url in enumerate(urls):
    r_response = requests.head(url)

    try:
        Response_Number = r_response.status_code
        sheet.write(index, 0, url)
        sheet.write(index, 1, Response_Number)

    except Exception:
        sheet.write(index, 0, url)
        sheet.write(index, 1, "Failed to Fetch Response")

book.save("Response Output.xls")
```

and below are the urls, save them into an excel, I have added a url "nitinkansal121.com" which doesnot exist. This breaks the code. If this url is removed them code runs fine.

```
https://clk.omgt5.com/?AID=183476&PID=9319&WID=33968
http://clk.omgt5.com/?AID=183476&PID=9166&WID=33968
http://clk.omgt5.com/?AID=183476&PID=14173&WID=33968
http://www.nitinkansal121.com/
http://clk.omgt5.com/?AID=183476&PID=9394&WID=33968
```

Comment: Try to add a try/except block on the actual request?

Comment: At what line does the error occur and what is the error? My guess is you get a NoneType for r_response. In that case, check for it by if r_response:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`requests.head` will raise an exception if passed a URL on a non-existent domain.

You could replace:

```
r_response = requsts.head(url)
```

with something like:

```
try:
    r_response = requests.head(url)
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
    sheet.write(index, 0 , url)
    sheet.write(index, 1, "Connection error")
```